# Show all windows OS X keyboard shortcut for mavericks

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-mavericks

Is there a keyboard shortcut for OSX Mavericks to show all windows, even the minimized or hidden ones for an application?

I hate having to use my mouse to click on the Chrome icon to open my other chrome windows.

[image: Show all Windows example]

Comment: did you find a solution? as a workaround, i use [witchy](http://manytricks.com/witch). it allows me to option-tab to all windows, hidden or not.

Comment: @MikeD I never found a native solution. I will check out Witchy, thanks!

Comment: it bugs me too; i look every few weeks and will let you know if I ever find anything. good luck

Answer (score 42):

The keyboard shortcut to show all windows for an application is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> then switch between these windows using arrow keys.

To change the keys used for the shortcut to whatever you want, go to System *Preferences-> Keyboard-> Shortcuts-> Mission Control-> Application Windows*.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am really needing a solution that works with minimized windows as well. I wonder if there are any third party apps that help with this?

Comment: In Yosemite Ctrl+Down WILL show minimized windows as well.  I just verified it.

Comment: How do we switch between these windows after CTRL+[DOWN] ?

Comment: Ctrl+Up shows all windows for all applications. Found this question when trying to figure out how to show all windows, not just for a particular application so thought I'd mention it here for others.

Answer (score 3):

It's under the system preferences for Mission Control: there's a shortcut defined there for "Application windows", currently set to ctrl + down arrow

Works for open and minimised windows for your currently chosen application.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>▲  (up arrow)</kbd> works on my Mac

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a "hot corner" and select "Application Windows". Also you would see the file history in a banner so that you could also access to your files that are minimised.